# how can I extract elements for this list

Tags: python, list

I got a List like this:

```
contents = [INSERT['new' at(41.74, 33.747)],
            INSERT['new' at(85.421, 34.221)],
            INSERT['new' at(57.848, 45.294)],
            INSERT['new' at(66.47, 19.93)],
            INSERT['new' at(70.071, 37.06)],
            INSERT['new' at(87.979, 22.958)],
            INSERT['new' at(46.098, 24.473)],
            LWPOLYLINE[((58.805, 38.48), (56.436, 23.622))],
            LWPOLYLINE[((68.375, 28.732), (79.556, 22.013))],
            LWPOLYLINE[((101.065, 41.603), (101.065, 29.3))],
            LINE[(99.644, 26.272) to(109.593, 36.02)],
            LINE[(97.938, 15.388) to(108.55, 18.132)],
            LINE[(87.231, 11.129) to(71.502, 15.388)]]
```

all I want is to extract the numbers from every element to manipulate it, when I call `contents[0]`,all I have is `INSERT['new' at (57.848, 45.294)]` and I dont know what is the structure of this element to manipulate it.

Comment: From where you are getting this list?

Comment: Please use markdown to make your post more readable. For instance, separate your code and data examples form the rest by a blank line and indent them with 4 spaces

Comment: I hate to break it to you but that code is full of syntax errors

Comment: I got this list from dxfgrabber module basically it describes the entities in a dxf drawing.

Comment: The problem is that it is not a valid list, it has `[ ]`, but the content is syntactically incorrect

Comment: if its not a valid list then what is it ? I mean python does not give me any error when I call any element from this list.

Comment: I find that hard to believe because when I copy your code just to construct a list I get multiple syntax errors. Perhaps INSERT, LINE etc are functions you made and did not show here?

Answer (score -1):

You have to iteratively run over a list of items

```
    for con in contents:
      item = contents[con] # this will give each item of a list
        #then here apply your logic
```

Comment: I tried your answer it gave me this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 2, in <module>
    item=contents[con]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not Insert

Comment: You cannot iterate over `contents` because it's not a valid list

Comment: First of all your list is not valid. My code was just to give the items of a list and then you can do processing on the items the way you want it. Had the list provided by you was valid then the code would have worked.

Comment: @TimCastelijns i agree with you. when we try to construct the list it gives error on the 1st line itself.

Comment: @TarekAbouElWafa please check your list.